# Cannot read property 'createComponent'?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Full code is:

```
export class FileSaveDialogComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
   @ViewChild("target", { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) target;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.target);
    const component = this.createComponent();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
  }

}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="savefile-content" #target></div>
```

Using:

```
<vr-savefile-dialog
  (saveCallback)="saveCallback($event)"
  [title]="'Save profile'"
  [type]="'profile'"
></vr-savefile-dialog>
```

Why I get a error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined
    at FileSaveDialogComponent.ngAfterViewInit
```

and undefined in line:

`console.log(this.target);`

Create component is, that returns specific component:

```
    switch (this.type) {
      case "profile":
        return SaveProfileDialogComponent;
      case "project":
        return SaveProjectDialogComponent;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does createComponent function return?

Comment: Return specific compnent return SaveProfileDialogComponent;

Comment: Can you share createComponent method code also?

Comment: Yes, see please

Comment: Problem is in `this.target` it is undefined

Comment: do you have createComponent() in the same component?

Comment: In which component you have <div class="savefile-content" #target></div> element?

Comment: In `FileSaveDialogComponent` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting and seeing your entire code it seems that the container with the child you try to access is not yet generated on screen because of an *ngFor condition, it is important to note that you can only access a child with @viewChild if it is already generated. Happy to help!

Comment: I try to get element `<div class="savefile-content" #target></div>` from the same component  `FileSaveDialogComponent`

Comment: Could we discus in chat?

Comment: How to move in chat here?